# A lot of 'cannot resolve symbol' errors in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I built my project from Build > Rebuild Project and suddenly I got a lot of 'cannot resolve symbol' errors, and lot of text went 'red' and building the project gave errors as follows:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :generateDebugSources, :generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:clean
:app:clean UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
C:\Users\HP\AndroidstudioProjects\JtEventsAndAnnouncements.BAK3\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(16, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
Error:(17, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(18, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(21, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 16.514 secs
Information:5 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

This is my styles.xml:

```
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

styles-v11:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

styles-v14:

```
    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

My layout design tab for one fragment shows the following error:

```
 Rendering Problems NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.  The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going on?

**Update:**

Here's my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }


    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

}
```

Comment: clean your project and then build it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your XML :

```
    <resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
   </style>
 <resources>
```

Then Rebuild &  Restart

Comment: Okay so I put this code in styles.xml. Rebuilt and restarted but rebuild shows same errors. Did not work. There are a lot of errors in the java files as well as many things have gone 'red'. Really need help with this this just happened out of the blue!

Comment: @AhmedZafar Please post your build.gradle

Comment: set minSdkVersion 15 & test please

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: comment out  support:appcompat in your gradle . and check what happen

Comment: So I still do not have the answer to this,